# Enabling Developer mode on a webos TV (LG)

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv

Trying to enable developer mode on an LG TV with WebOS via [these instructions](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/) so I can install the [twitch.tv app for webos](https://github.com/PatrickRorth/Twitch.TV) but I cannot find the Developer App anywhere on my smart tv. Not in Smart World or any other store page I could find.

I've tried looking at similar questions on here but they all say something like "go to the "content store""  or  "go to "lg store"" **which, for me atleast, aren't a thing on the page where the apps are displayed** (smart home, I think?)

I've installed the SDK on my computer incase I need to do something with that.

I'm really confused and would like any help possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it seems I am a bit stupid and didn't realise that my TV isn't WebOS. It's netcast.

Answer (score 1):

To enable developer mode on LG WebOS TV you need to install **Developer mode** app from LG Content Store

1. On remote press Home button
2. Go to LG Content Store
3. Search 'Developer mode' on LG Content Store
4. Install 'Developer mode' app
5. from this application you can enable Developer mode

Comment: My LG webOS TV 24LJ4840-WU does not have "Search" in LG Content Store, so I can't search for Developer Mode. I looked through all the listed content, and it's not there. Any ideas how to get Developer Mode otherwise?